# WHERE filter on different values using a CASE

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

This seems to be a popular scenario yet I cannot seem to implement a solution from the previous answers on the topic.

I need to do something like this in SQL Server 2012:

```
DECLARE @conditionVarChar AS VARCHAR(MAX) = 'Use ham'
DECLARE @food AS VARCHAR(MAX) = 'ham'
DECLARE @somethingElse VARCHAR(MAX) = 'somethingelse'

SELECT *
FROM tempTable
--Here is my issue
WHERE CASE WHEN @conditionVarChar LIKE '%ham%' --If there is 'ham' in this varchar
           THEN @food = tempTable.Food --Then filter from this
           ELSE @somethingElse = tempTable.SomethingElse --Else, filter on something completely different
           END
```

Thanks

Comment: really dynamic SQL is the best way to do this....

Comment: if its just a few items, you can always do it as an IF/THEN... example if its HAM then SELECT * FROM temptable where food = ham etc.

Comment: Not sure if I understood your comment, but I need to select from the same table regardless...I just need two completely different WHERE clauses dependent on what @conditionVarChar contains

Comment: I was saying that if there are multiple "conditions" that you will be putting then you can use dynamic sql to do that. If you simply have ham or something else then a simple if then is a more easier approach.

Comment: The idea behind dynamic SQL is you declare a variable, then you set the text to the SQL statement. Then you execute that SQL statement. You can dyamically build it by adding text to the variable you declared. Let me know if you need some help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't really need a `CASE` statement to do this, you can just filter on sets of criteria and use `OR`:

```
WHERE (@conditionVarChar LIKE '%ham%' AND @food = tempTable.Food)
  OR  (@somethingElse = tempTable.SomethingElse)
```

Depending on actual criteria it may be more practical to use dynamic sql to build criteria lists.